# Find the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^+} (\sin x)^\frac1{\ln x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to0^+} (\sin x)^{\large {\frac1 {\ln x}}}$

Here's what I did:

$\begin{align}\lim_{x \to 0^+} (\sin x)^{\large \frac1{\ln x}}&(1) =\lim e^{\large {\ln( { (\sin x)^\frac1{\ln x}})}} \ \ \\ 
&(2) = \lim_{x \to0^+} e^{\large {{\frac1{\ln x}}\ln( { (\sin x)})}}  \ \  \\
& (3)= \lim_{x \to0^+} e^{\large {\frac{\ln\sin x}{\ln x}}}   \ \  \\
&(4) = \lim_{x \to0^+} e^{\large {\ln\frac{ \sin x}{ x}}} \ \\
& (5)= \lim_{x \to0^+} \frac{ \sin x}{ x} = 1
\end{align}$

But I know this is wrong because when I plot it it goes to e.

I am now stuck on step 3.

Any advice please ?

PS: we can't use derivation or integration, nor Taylor's theorem because we haven't covered that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

continuing from step 3 we have
$$\displaystyle = \lim_{x \to0^+} e^{\large {\frac{\ln \sin x}{\ln x}}}$$
$$=\displaystyle e^{\lim_{x \to0^+} {\large {\frac{\ln \sin x}{\ln x}}}}$$

So the problem boils down to evaluating
$$=\displaystyle \lim_{x \to0^+} {\large {\frac{\ln \sin x}{\ln x}}}$$

I claim that for $0<x<\pi/2$ that the following holds
$$\sin x \lt x \lt \tan x$$
[image: Figure 1]

In *figure 1*, we let $OC=OA=1$. In other words, $Arc\:CA=x$ is an arc of a unit circle. The shortest distance from point $C$ to line  $AO$ is line $CE=\sin x$ (because $CE\perp OA$). Another path from point $C$ to line $OA$ is arc $CA$ (which is longer than CE because it is not the shortest path). So we have at the very least
$$\sin x \lt x$$
Now we need to show that line $BA=\tan x \gt x$.
Lines $AD$ and $CD$ are both tangent to arc $CA$. $CD+DA$ is longer than arc $CA$ because the set of points bound by sector $OCA \subset $the set of points bound by quadrilateral $OCDA$, both of which are convex sets. This means that the perimeter of quadrilateral $OCDA$ must be longer than the perimeter of the sector $OCA$ (as per *Archimedes, On the Sphere and Cylinder Book I*). But both the sector and the quadrilateral both have sides $OC$ and $OA$, so we have
$$CA=x<DC+DA$$
But $BD>CD$ because it is the hypotenuse in $\triangle BCD$ we have
$$\tan x = BA = BD+DA\gt CD+DA \gt CA=x \gt \sin x$$

Because $\sin x$ is closer to zero than $x$ which is closer to zero than $\tan x$, $\ln \sin x$ must be closer to $-\infty$ than $\ln x$ which must be closer to $-\infty$ than $\ln\tan x$, so we have
$$\ln\sin x \lt \ln x \lt \ln\tan x$$
$$\ln\sin x \lt \ln x \lt \ln\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$$
$$\ln\sin x \lt \ln x \lt \ln\sin x - \ln\cos x$$
$$\frac{\ln\sin x}{\ln x} \gt 1 \gt \frac{\ln\sin x}{\ln x} - \frac{\ln\cos x}{\ln x}$$
or
$$\frac{\ln\sin x}{\ln x} - \frac{\ln\cos x}{\ln x}\lt 1 \lt \frac{\ln\sin x}{\ln x} $$
But
$$\lim_{x \to0^+}\frac{\ln\cos x}{\ln x}=0$$
so we have
$$\lim_{x \to0^+}\frac{\ln\sin x}{\ln x} \le 1 \le \lim_{x \to0^+}\frac{\ln\sin x}{\ln x} $$
which implies that
$$\lim_{x \to0^+}\frac{\ln\sin x}{\ln x} = 1$$
thus
$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to0^+}\bigg(\sin x\bigg)^{\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle\ln x}} = e$$

Comment: Very nice answer.

Answer (score 8):

Your mistake is in the fourth equality: It is not true that

$$\ln \left(\frac a b\right) = \frac{\ln a}{\ln b}$$

Answer (score 3):

**METHOD 1: l'Hopital's Rule**

I will add to the answer provided by T. Bongers:

So, you have: $$\lim \exp(\frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{\ln(x)}) \\ = \lim \exp(\frac{\cos(x)/\sin(x)}{1/x}) \\ = \lim \exp(\frac{\cos(x)\cdot x}{\sin(x)}) \\ = \exp(\lim [(\frac{\sin(x)}{x})^{-1}\cdot \cos(x)]) =\exp(1).$$

**METHOD 2: Squeeze Theorem and Taylor's Theorem**

As in method 1, we have $$\lim \exp(\frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{\ln(x)}) \\ \leq \lim \exp(\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(x)}) = e.$$

Also, $$\lim \exp(\frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{\ln(x)}) \\ \geq \lim \exp(\frac{\ln(x)+\ln(1-x^2/6)}{\ln(x)}) \\ \geq e\cdot \lim \exp(\frac{-x^2/6-x^4/(72(1+(x^2/6))^2)}{x}) \\ \geq e\cdot \exp( \lim (-x/6-x^3/(72(1+(x^2/6))^2))) = e\cdot 1 = e.$$

Comment: I never saw this exp notation...

Comment: Well, $\exp(x) = e^x$. Nothing new here.

Comment: OK, how can you break the ln into these fractions ?

Comment: You can't. Here you want to use l'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: Oh I see. We'll we can't use derivations yet because we haven't covered that.

Comment: Then another method would be to use the squeeze theorem. The limit is definitely bounded above by $e$.

Comment: Let me write that up.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to use it from step 3 ?

Comment: @ChrisK : I didn't read your solution, but you need to note that only the limit from the right can make sense.

Comment: @ChrisK We haven't covered Taylor's either... Either way thank you.

Comment: Specifically then what have you been taught. What can you assume? You need something to control the logarithms.

Comment: @ChrisK well we just learned the definition of a function, basic limit arithmetic of functions and continuity. Is there another way to do this ?

Comment: Well, for example you know that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{sin(x)}{x} = 1$. Obviously you didn't prove this with l'Hopital's (so did you use a geometric proof?).

Comment: Yes the geometric proof. This was what I was aiming for but I got stuck on step 3.

Comment: so? is there any other solution without using Taylor series or derivatives?

Comment: @guynaa no clue...

Comment: Well, the upper bound you can easily get; however, there is no easily apparent way to get the lower bound unless you compare the following comparison that: $\lim \log(\sin(x))/\log(x) \geq \lim \sin(x)/x = 1$. This is basically what I proved rigorously with the Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Without using hopital or calculus we can do it this way:

For x we have $\sin(x) \le x$ and so therefore $\ln(\sin(x)) \le \ln(x)$ therefore: $(\sin(x))^{1/\ln(x)} \le e$

but $\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \le \frac{\ln(\sin(x))}{\ln(x)} $ because $a/b \le \log_b(a)$

therefore $e^{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}} \le (\sin(x))^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}} \le e$

and now by the squeeze theorem $\lim_{x \to 0^+} (\sin(x))^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}} = e$

Comment: Why is that true:  $(\sin(x))^{1/\ln(x)} \le e$
?

Comment: $\ln(\sin(x))/\ln(x) \le 1$ therefore $(\sin(x))^{1/\ln(x)} = e^{\ln(\sin(x))/\ln(x)} \le e^1 = e$

Comment: $a/b \le \log_b(a)$ isn't true. $\ln x > x/e$ ?

Comment: $-5<-3,$ but $\frac{-5}{-3}>1$.